# function of this code in matlab R(:,P>.6/2)=0;

Tags: matlab

I am reading a matlab code find have some difficulties in figuring it. the problems is that: R is a 4X5X6 matrix and P is a 5X6 matrix. what's the function of this line R(:,P>.6/2)=0?

it seems that this line will change some elements to zeros, but I do not understand the judgement basis and the relationship between R and P.

thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It first gets all the elements of P that satisfies the condition P>0.3. The result is used to index the R array, more particularly the second and third dimension.

To give you a concrete exemple, everytime there is a value over 0.3 at position (i, j) then all the R(k, i, j) (with k taking all the possible values) are set to 0.

Best,